# Angular 2 ng-build every time when code changed?

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I developing a MEAN app. In the past I only used Angular and ng-serve was a bless to try code out and develop.

Now in combination with Node.js as a server, that loads Angular in my so-called "public" folder, I have to do "ng build" every time and it does go through all files, even if I just changed a little code on one component Typescript.

My question? What can I do to develop faster using Node.js and Angular 2 without hitting every time "ng build" on changed code?

Comment: Please provide your package.json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is you can use concurrently library and liteserver.
Install them as dependencies in package.json
Using concurrently run the typescript compiler and liteserver then page will be loaded automatically when ever the code is modified.

```
{
"scripts" : {
  "start" : "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
  "lite" : "lite-server",
  "tsc":"tsc",
  "tsc:w":"tsc -w"
}
"devDependencies":{
   "concurently":"^2.0.0",
   "lite-server":"2.2.0"
}
}
```

Include the above code in your package.json file and run npm install which will install the dependencies.
Then run npm start which will start the server and compile the code when ever u change and reload the page

Comment: I have found a solution. It's called 'ng build --watch'. Give it  try. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 6):

I think `ng build --watch` can help.

Comment: It is better to add this as a comment.